# Organização dos códigos gerados pelo WindowBuilder

Tags: java, swing, window-builder

Estou usando o WindowBuilder para desenhar a interface gráfica, mas tem uma coisa que é meio chato nele, que é o seguinte. Quando eu crio um JLabel por exemplo, ele declara o JLabel dentro do construtor, me impossibilitando de usar ele diretamente em outros métodos. Teria alguma forma de que automaticamente tudo que eu criasse fosse diretamente para a classe, ficasse organizado no topo, para que eu não tenha que fazer isso manualmente com todos os componentes que eu tenha que manipular em mais de uma classe?

Comment: O estranho é que alguns componentes ele cria direto na classe, ao invés do método construtor, como por exemplo o JTextField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei a solução, caso alguém prefira que os componentes sejam declarados foram do construtor, pode fazer a seguinte configuração:

No eclipse acesse a aba WINDOW > PREFERENCES > WINDOWBUILDER > SWING > CODE GENERATION e na janelinha que está escrito: variable generation, é só selecionar **Field**, e depois apertar ok.

Comment: Muito útil a informação. Não conhecia esse menu.

Comment: Pois eh, sempre rejeitei usar o wb porcauda da desorganizaçao dos codigos, mas depois que descobri isso ai ficou muito melhor.